# Action for input-helper

Tags: ember.js

I have a textfield, which I want to have a 'dynamic' placeholder text (definied and managed in the view), but I also want it to have an action defined for it. I tried the two following lines:

```
{{ input id="test" placeholder=view.text action expand target="view"}}

<input type="text" id="test" placeholder="{{view.text}}" {{action expand target="view"}} />
```

Both are not working. So my question is, is there a way to achieve what I want or would it be easier to have a focus handler in the view, which just filters for the id (and then calls the expand function)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to do it like this:

```
<input type="text" id="test" {{bindAttr placeholder=view.text}} {{action expand target="view"}} />
```

See [here](http://jsbin.com/axihur/7/edit) for a working example.

Hope it helps

Comment: AAhh yes, how did I not find that. Thank you

Answer (score 12):

If you want to stick to input helpers, you can do something like this:

```
{{input placeholder=view.text action="expand" targetObject=view}}
```

Notice that targetObject should **not** be a string.